# Wildcards in cache keys

Tags: java, caching

I have a scenario in which I send 3 parameters to an external service and expect a result. I want to find an elegant way to cache the result.

The issue is that the 3 parameters have hierarchy between them. Something like:

1. City
2. Street
3. Building

I want to be able to cache with wild cards on lower levels than "City". For example:

- The cache contains the key "NY, *, 453" and key "NY, 16st, *"
- For a request with params "NY, 15st, 453" That's a hit and for "NY, 15st,444" that's a miss.

Using just a plain object with '*' marking wildcards would cause having many "if"s in order to check the conditions. I thought about overriding the `equals` and the `toString` methods but I couldn't find the right way to do it.

Comment: what if all the elements for "NY, *, 453" don't fit your main memory?

Comment: Use MongoDB / JSON DB

Comment: @Leo - Not sure I got the question right but the idea is only to keep the keys with the wildcards, not all of the elements that fit the key.

Comment: @ControlAltDel - I'm looking for something on the code level, not storage.

Comment: errr... then what exactly are you planning to cache? The keys?

Comment: @Leo - The values that are returned from the external service. That's a computation result and I'm trying to avoid the computation + the roundtrip of repeated results.

Comment: aren't [computation results] = [elements that fit the key]?

Comment: @Leo not necessarily. The keys are kept according to predefined rules. So if there's a rule for "NY, *, 453" I don't need to keep a key for every permutation in which * is a concrete street name. I just want to cache those keys according to the rules I mentioned to avoid the computation and roundtrip.

Comment: sorry, I think I really don't understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think that trying to do this as simple strings will be painful to the Nth degree.

I'd recommend a different solution.

Not being a Java developer, I can't give you exact syntax, but the P-code should be close enough.

```
class Address {

   // Properties.
   City: string,
   Street: string,
   Building: string
}

class Addresses {
    Add: List<Address>

     public bool GetHit(city, street, building) {
       foreach(var add in Add) {
         if (add.city == city) && (add.street == street) && (add.building == building) {
           return true;
         }
       }
       return false;
     }


    public bool GetHitByKey(city, street, building) {
      // First, check to see if there is a wildcard on the street
      if GetHit(city, "*", building) {
        return true;
      }

      if GetHit(city, "*", "*") {
        return true;
      }

      return GetHit(city, street, building);
    }
}
```

**Todo:**

- Pass an object instead of 3 paramaters around
- Use a binary search rather than linear.